# How to update keys of map in dart

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart, async-await, hashmap

I have a simple map "objects" lets assume this :

```
{
ServoP180V1: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, 
ServoP180V3: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}
ServoP180V5: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}
}
```

How I can sort the keys in such way that they will be in an order, like this:

```
{
ServoP180V1: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, 
ServoP180V2: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}
ServoP180V3: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}
}
```

I tried this code but it has problems with returning null sometimes, not sure Im in right way

```
  sortObjects() {
    int i = 1;
    for (var key in objects.keys) {
      objects.update(
        key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + i.toString(),
        null,
      );
      i++;
    }
  }
```

```
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
```

also this way

```
  sortObjects() {
    int i = 1;
    objects.forEach((key, value) {
      objects.update(
        key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + i.toString(),
        (existingValue) => value,
        ifAbsent: () => value,
      );
      i++;
    });
  }
```

giving such an error

```
Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration:
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You seem to be changing the keys from the old to new structure.  and what is .update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are changing the key during the foearch loop, this is illegal. I would change the keys by generating another map and then replacing the old one. It is an answer.

[Map.update()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/update.html)

Update method of the map only updates the content of the key and only if it exists, but does not change the key itself. I didn't find anything related to changing keys for maps at runtime.

```
Map<String, dynamic> oldMap = {
  "ServoP180V1": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0},
  "ServoP180V3": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0},
  "ServoP180V5": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0}
};
Map<String, dynamic> newMap = {};
int i = 1;
oldMap.keys.toList().forEach((key) {
  newMap.addAll({
    "${key.substring(0, key.length - 1)}$i":
        oldMap[key]
  });
  i++;
});
print(oldMap);
print(newMap);
```

result:

```
{ServoP180V1: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V3: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V5: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}}
{ServoP180V1: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V2: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V3: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chance using temp map was key solution. I just used to think maybe there is a way do it straight in map)))

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final objects = {
    'ServoP180V1': {'X': 100.0, 'Y': 0.0}, 
    'ServoP180V3': {'X': 100.0, 'Y': 0.0},
    'ServoP180V5': {'X': 100.0, 'Y': 0.0}
  };

  var keys = objects.keys.toList()..sort();
  var newData = <String, Map<String, double>>{};

  keys.forEach((k) => newData[k] = objects[k]);

  print(newData);
}
```

Result:

```
{ServoP180V1: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V3: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}, ServoP180V5: {X: 100.0, Y: 0.0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, dynamic> oldMap = {
  "ServoP180V1": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0},
  "ServoP180V3": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0},
  "ServoP180V5": {"X": 100.0, "Y": 0.0}
};
int j = 1;
Map<String, dynamic> newMap2 = oldMap
  .map((key, value) => MapEntry('ServoP180V${j++}',value);
 );
print(newMap2); // {ServoP180V1: {X: 100, Y: 0}, ServoP180V2: {X: 100, Y: 0}, ServoP180V3: {X: 100, Y: 0}}
```